# Exclude some part from background blend mode

Tags: css, background-image, background-color, mix-blend-mode

I try to achieve effect similar to Photoshop multiply via code on my project. At the same time i try to exclude some elements that are in child div to be affected by it (like text layers) - and i hit in the wall. Tried already adding additional div's setting different z-index's or go with absolute position.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPKBKd) you can find pen with example of the problem:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eligendi est eius unde autem dolore adipisci perspiciatis laboriosam reiciendis placeat! Eveniet, quam? Vitae sit saepe quam delectus fugiat, dolores necessitatibus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: #0079ff;
     mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/fMY2f9/Bg1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Summary:** Child element's of 'child div' are affected by multiply. Is there a way to prevent that?

Screenshots:

[image: Multiply has been applied but it also affect text layers.]

[image]

Comment: Please post your code here. Checkout [MCVE] to make sure you follow guidelines - you need a minimal example.

Comment: We can't debug images, we need the code that **reproduce** the issue described.

Comment: Yep.  i published a little to early - my bad :). I provided all necessary information now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pseudo element for the background to avoid this:

```css
.inner {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/fMY2f9/Bg1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.main::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #0079ff;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eligendi est eius unde autem dolore adipisci perspiciatis laboriosam reiciendis placeat! Eveniet, quam? Vitae sit saepe quam delectus fugiat, dolores necessitatibus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, 
Yep this - solved problem. There was some strange bug with font render. Sometimes fonts on the top of layer do not rendered properly but removing backface-visibility solved this issue.